# Deriving skew t density function through convolution representation?

Tags: distributions, references, density-function, skewness, convolution

I am studying on skew t distribution,  so i need its density function. I want to derive that via, integral of convolution representation. Could you please help me and introduce a good source?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i mean the part of azzalini and capitano(2003) paper.they introduced skew t distribution as a convolution of skew normal and gamma distributions and said after some simple algebra we can derive density function.I trided many times but i couldent do this algebra

Comment: Which equation(s), e.g., in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2342 are you talking about,  please?

Comment: thanks again, equation 26. How can I derive equation 26?